# New action every new click

Tags: javascript, click, action

EDITED

To make it more specific.

This is my code.

```
<div class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_file" id="attachment_1_container_div" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <label for="attachment_1">Συννημένα:</label>
    <input id="attachment_1" class="" title="" type="file" name="attachment_1">
    <img src="http://www.saveursdebacchus.com/medias/images/plus-sign.png" id="plus" onclick="addfield()" style="width: 35px; position: relative; top: 4em; cursor: pointer;">
</div>
<div class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_file" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 11.5em; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;height: 38px;" id="attachment_2_container_div">
    <input id="attachment_2" class="" title="" type="file" name="attachment_2" style="position: relative; top: -1em;">
    <img src="http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons/3d-glossy-orange-orbs-icons-alphanumeric/104914-3d-glossy-orange-orb-icon-alphanumeric-minus-sign-simple.png" id="minus" onclick="removefield()" style="width: 35px;position: relative;left: 3em;top: 0.095em; cursor: pointer;">
</div>
<div class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_file" id="attachment_3_container_div" style="position: relative; left: 11.5em; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="attachment_3" value="" alt="ghost">
    <input id="attachment_3" class="" title="" type="file" name="attachment_3">
</div>
```

What I want is, the `img#plus` when is clicked to display the next field (e.g `div#attachment_2_container_div`) and the image to go down closed to new displayed field.
This for 2 times (first for `div#attachment_2_container_div` and second for `div#attachment_3_container_div`). And also the inverse method with `img#minus`.

I think it needs more code than 5-10 lines.. Thats why I asked little by little.

I'll follow a more simply way (I will give images in every row and on display of a div I'll take the result I want). Sorry for any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Moves the button down incrementally on the number of clicks the button recieves, so the 'jumps' get 1em larger each time, you can adjust the way the 'counter' variable increments in addfile to change the 'jumps'

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, relatively unclear question

[revision to include 1,3,5em jumps]

```
    var imgObj = null;
    var counter = 0;
    function init(){
       imgObj = document.getElementById('plus');
       imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
       imgObj.style.top = '1em'; 
    }
    function addfile(){
       counter++;
       if(counter==1){
           imgObj.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) + 1 + 'em';
        }
        else if(counter==2){
           imgObj.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) + 3 + 'em';

        }
        else if(counter==3){
           imgObj.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) + 5 + 'em';
        }
        else
           imgObj.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) + 0 + 'em';
    }
    window.onload =init;
```

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure what u want , but according to what i understood by ur question i have done a fiddle, here is the link, hope its what u needed :)  [fiddle click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Faizan_Alam/yxtk89uq/)

```
var my=null; //dont consider this line, m new here, pls ignore
```

I have done  modification in your HTML, and functions are a mixture of both javascript and jquery.